# video/mp4 vs video/mpeg mime type

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, mime-type

I need to add some .mp4 videos to a course in my LMS (Moodle) on a Windows 2008 R2 server. I'm using IIS 7.5 as the web server. While searching the www for the correct way to do it I've found several references that say you should use "Mime Type = video/mp4" for the .mp4 extension. Other references say you should use "Mime Type = video/mpeg".

I tried both. And both seem to work. So which one SHOULD I use for .mp4 files? "video/mpeg" or "video/mp4"? Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by [RFC4337](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4337) `video/mp4` is the preferable mime type for .mp4

BTW for more compatibility (mobile device, etc.) and more functionality (streaming, etc.). If it is possible in your case, I would recommand you to upload your video to youtube or use [IIS Media services](http://www.iis.net/media).

Comment: Thanks Cyril. RFC4337 looks interesting, thanks mentioning it and for the link. Youtube is not an option, but I will certainly consider IIS Media Services. Thanks.